# Using Minecraft's PlayerController.windowClick()?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm currently trying to figure out how to move an item in the player's inventory from one slot to another.

I get that for this action to work, it has to be sent as a packet to the server, and I've read in the PlayerControllerMP class, that windowClick() "Handles slot clicks, sends a packet to the server."

This code should open the inventory and move the item from the first slot to the second slot in the hotbar. However, when I run it, it only ever opens the inventory and nothing happens to the item.

```
Minecraft.getMinecraft().displayGuiScreen(new GuiInventory(Minecraft.getMinecraft().player));
Minecraft.getMinecraft().playerController.windowClick(Minecraft.getMinecraft().player.inventoryContainer.windowId, 0, 0, ClickType.PICKUP, Minecraft.getMinecraft().player);
Minecraft.getMinecraft().playerController.windowClick(Minecraft.getMinecraft().player.inventoryContainer.windowId, 1, 0, ClickType.PICKUP, Minecraft.getMinecraft().player);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. The indecies in the player inventory go like this:

0   crafting output

1–4   crafting input

5–8   armor

9–35   main inventory

36–44   hotbar

45   Offhand slot

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact fields of `ClickType`, or anything to do with Minecraft modding for that matter, but what I can see is that you use `ClickType.PICKUP` on the second slot, which you are moving something to, but shouldn't it be something like `ClickType.DROP`? Like I said, I don't know that much on Minecraft modding, so I don't know the exact fields, so there should be a field that drops the item or releases the item or something like that. What I do know, however, is that it looks like you're trying to pick up the item in the slot your moving it to.

```
Minecraft.getMinecraft().playerController.windowClick(Minecraft.getMinecraft().player.inventoryContainer.windowId, 1, 0, ClickType.DROP /* Or it could be ClickType.RELEASE? */ Minecraft.getMinecraft().player);
```

Comment: Sadly, there is no such thing as ClickType.Drop. I'm pretty sure that another problem is causing this, as I've tried similar things with the other ClickType Methods and none of them worked.